# How to emulate double precision using two floats in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es, floating-point, glsl

I am working on creating deep zooms into the Mandelbrot set, and as you might know OpenGL ES does not support the `double`  data type. The highest precision that it can offer is that of a  IEEE 754 `float`. On Googling, and after a lot of searching, I came across this blog: https://blog.cyclemap.link/2011-06-09-glsl-part2-emu/ that is totally dedicated to this topic. But, unfortunately I cannot understand the code for addition, subtraction and multiplication, presented there. Especially, I can't understand the part that deals with the error correction and carrying. It would be extremely helpful, if you could explain to me, the depth of the error checking and carrying over of bits from low parts to higher.
So, far I only understand the fundamental concept of splitting the double into two floats. But, the implementation of the basic operations is unclear to me. It would be very helpful if the explanation is done using the context of binary numbers.

Comment: I managed to use this in my CPU mandelbrot (was a bit problem as my mandelbrot is a template for numeric data type so I needed to make a wrapper class encapsulating my `vec3` and `HP32_???`  into class with supported arithmetic operators and stuff). After that I still do not see improvement from the `float` ... the rendering is slightly different but not better nor worse visually  and if I use high zooms the result is blank. So I assume there must be some overflow/underflow issue happening along the computation (maybe some edge case) want to analyze further.. The speed however is hugely SLOOW

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First the basic principle that is used to deal with this. Once you add or substract numbers with high exponent difference the result gets rounded:

```
12345600000 + 8.76542995683848E-4 = 12345600000
```

Now as I showed you in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66719738/2521214) we can store our numbers as sum of more floats for example `vec2, vec3, vec4` which are still floats but together can combine to bigger overall mantissa bitwidth. The link in your question is not using exponent ranges like I did but uses difference between rounded and not rounded results. However the linked lib uses just `vec2` which is still much less precise than native `64` bit `double` as mantissa of `double` has `53` bits and `float` has just `24` bits so `24+24 = 48 < 53` that is why I decided to use `vec3`. Now the trick is to obtain the rounding error. For the same example as above:

```
a=12345600000 
b=8.76542995683848E-4
c=a+b=12345600000
```

the `a,b` are `float` operands for `+` operation and `c` is rounded result. so the difference `e` can be obtained like this:

```
e=c-a; // e= 0
e-=b;  // e=-8.76542995683848E-4
e=-e;  // e=+8.76542995683848E-4
```

where `e` is the stuff that should be added to `c` in order to get not rounded result.

Now if we store some part of number in each component of `vec3` then we can try to add this `e` to all of them (always removing added part from `e`) until `e` is zero.

So if `c.x+e` does round we add it to `c.y` and so on... Based on this I managed to compose this:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- High Precision float ver: 1.000 ---------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _GLSL_HP32
#define _GLSL_HP32
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// helper functions (internals)
void hp32_nor(vec3 &c)          // bubble sort c coordinates desc by magnitude
    {
    float x;
    if (fabs(c.x)<fabs(c.y)){ x=c.x; c.x=c.y; c.y=x; }
    if (fabs(c.x)<fabs(c.z)){ x=c.x; c.x=c.z; c.z=x; }
    if (fabs(c.y)<fabs(c.z)){ x=c.y; c.y=c.z; c.z=x; }
    }
void hp32_err(vec3 &c,vec3 &e)  // c+=e; apply rounding error e corection to c
    {
    float q;
    q=c.x; c.x+=e.x; e.x=e.x-(c.x-q);
    q=c.x; c.x+=e.y; e.y=e.y-(c.x-q);
    q=c.x; c.x+=e.z; e.z=e.z-(c.x-q);
    q=c.y; c.y+=e.x; e.x=e.x-(c.y-q);
    q=c.y; c.y+=e.y; e.y=e.y-(c.y-q);
    q=c.y; c.y+=e.z; e.z=e.z-(c.y-q);
    q=c.z; c.z+=e.x; e.x=e.x-(c.z-q);
    q=c.z; c.z+=e.y; e.y=e.y-(c.z-q);
    q=c.z; c.z+=e.z; e.z=e.z-(c.z-q);
    hp32_nor(c);
    }
void hp32_split(vec3 &h,vec3 &l,vec3 a) // (h+l)=a; split mantissas to half
    {
    const float n=8193.0; // 10000000000001 bin uses ~half of mantissa bits
    h=a*n;  // this shifts the a left by half of mantissa (almost no rounding yet)
    l=h-a;  // this will round half of mantissa as h,a have half of mantisa bits exponent difference
    h-=l;   // this will get rid of the `n*` part from number leaving just high half of mantisa from original a
    l=a-h;  // this is just the differenc ebetween original a and h ... so lower half of mantisa beware might change sign
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// double api (comment it out if double not present)
vec3 hp32_set(double a)                                             // double -> vec2
    {
    vec3 c;
    c.x=a; a-=c.x;
    c.y=a; a-=c.y;
    c.z=a; hp32_nor(c);
    return c;
    }
double hp32_getl(vec3 a){ double c; c=a.z+a.y; c+=a.x; return c; }  // vec2 -> double
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// normal api
vec3 hp32_set(float a){ return vec3(a,0.0,0.0); }                   // float -> vec2
float hp32_get(vec3 a){ float c; c=a.z+a.y; c+=a.x; return c; }     // vec2 -> float
vec3 hp32_add(vec3 a,vec3 b)                                        // = a+b
    {
    // c=a+b; addition
    vec3 c=a+b,e; float q;
    // e=(a+b)-c; rounding error
    c.x=a.x+b.x; e.x=c.x-a.x; e.x-=b.x;
    c.y=a.y+b.y; e.y=c.y-a.y; e.y-=b.y;
    c.z=a.z+b.z; e.z=c.z-a.z; e.z-=b.z;
    e=-e; hp32_err(c,e);
    return c;
    }
vec3 hp32_sub(vec3 a,vec3 b)                                        // = a-b
    {
    // c=a-b; substraction
    vec3 c=a-b,e; float q;
    // e=(a-b)-c; rounding error
    c.x=a.x+b.x; e.x=c.x-a.x; e.x+=b.x;
    c.y=a.y+b.y; e.y=c.y-a.y; e.y+=b.y;
    c.z=a.z+b.z; e.z=c.z-a.z; e.z+=b.z;
    e=-e; hp32_err(c,e);
    return c;
    }
vec3 hp32_mul_half(vec3 a,vec3 b)                                   // = a*b where a,b are just half of mantissas !!! internal call do not use this !!!
    {
    //  c = (a.x+a.y+a.z)*(b.x+b.y+b.z)     // multiplication of 2 expresions
    //  c = (a.x*b.x)+(a.x*b.y)+(a.x*b.z)   // expanded
    //     +(a.y*b.x)+(a.y*b.y)+(a.y*b.z)
    //     +(a.z*b.x)+(a.z*b.y)+(a.z*b.z)
    //  c = (a.x*b.x)                       // ordered desc by magnitude (x>=y>=z)
    //     +(a.x*b.y)+(a.y*b.x)
    //     +(a.x*b.z)+(a.z*b.x)+(a.y*b.y)
    //     +(a.y*b.z)+(a.z*b.y)
    //     +(a.z*b.z)
    vec3 c,e,f; float q,r;
    // c=a*b; (e,f)=(a*b)-c; multiplication
    c.x=(a.x*b.x);
    r=(a.x*b.y); q=c.x; c.x+=r; e.x=r-(c.x-q);
    r=(a.y*b.x); q=c.x; c.x+=r; e.y=r-(c.x-q);
    c.y=(a.x*b.z);
    r=(a.z*b.x); q=c.y; c.y+=r; e.z=r-(c.y-q);
    r=(a.y*b.y); q=c.y; c.y+=r; f.x=r-(c.y-q);
    c.z=(a.y*b.z);
    r=(a.z*b.y); q=c.z; c.z+=r; f.y=r-(c.z-q);
    r=(a.z*b.z); q=c.z; c.z+=r; f.z=r-(c.z-q);
    e=+hp32_add(e,f); hp32_err(c,e);
    return c;
    }
vec3 hp32_mul(vec3 a,vec3 b)                                        // = a*b
    {
    vec3 ah,al,bh,bl,c;
    // split operands to halves of mantissa
    hp32_split(ah,al,a);
    hp32_split(bh,bl,b);
    //  c = (ah+al)*(bh+bl) = ah*bh + ah*bl + al*bh + al*bl
    c=           hp32_mul_half(ah,bh) ;
    c=hp32_add(c,hp32_mul_half(ah,bl));
    c=hp32_add(c,hp32_mul_half(al,bh));
    c=hp32_add(c,hp32_mul_half(al,bl));
    return c;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For now I tested this only on CPU side (C++). In order to use it in GLSL Just comment out or remove the double api functions Which I used to verify accuracy. And change the `fabs` to `abs` or declare:

```
float fabs(float x){ return abs(x); }
```

Again I have some normalization function `hp32_nor` which sorts the components by magnitude so `fabs(x)>=fabs(y)>=fabs(z)` which is needed to get back to `float` and multiplication. The `+,-` does not need it.

The `hp32_err` is like addition between normal number and rounding error difference (its a bit horrible but it preserves accuracy as much as it can) described above.

**I did not test this extensively yet!!!** Looks like `+,-,*` operations are precise in comparison with `double`.

The multiplication implementation is a bit complex because `a*b` on floats has the result bitwidth of mantissa as sum of operands bitwidths. So to avoid rounding we need to first split the operands into halves. that can be done like this (analysed from the lib you linked):

```cpp
// split float into h,l
float a,h,l,n;
n=8193.0;   // n =               10000000000001.00000000000000000000b
a=123.4567; // a =                      1111011.01110100111010101000b
h=a*n;      // h =         11110110111100011000.11000000000000000000b
l=h-a;      // l =         11110110111010011101.01010000000000000000b
h-=l;       // h =                      1111011.01110000000000000000b
l=a-h;      // l =                            0.00000100111010101000b
```

so float has 24 bits of mantisa and 8193 is `(24/2)+1=13` bits wide. So once you multiply any float with it the result needs about half of mantissa bits more than present and get round off. The its just a matter of getting back to original operand scale and getting the other half as difference between new half and original float value. All of this is done in helper function `hp32_split`.

Now the multiplication `c=a*b` on halves look like this:

```cpp
c = (ah+al)*(bh+bl) = ah*bh + ah*bl + al*bh + al*bl
```

And each half multiplication `a?*b?` loos like this:

```
c = (a.x+a.y+a.z)*(b.x+b.y+b.z)     // multiplication of 2 expresions
c = (a.x*b.x)+(a.x*b.y)+(a.x*b.z)   // expanded
   +(a.y*b.x)+(a.y*b.y)+(a.y*b.z)
   +(a.z*b.x)+(a.z*b.y)+(a.z*b.z)
c = (a.x*b.x)                       // ordered desc by magnitude (x>=y>=z)
   +(a.x*b.y)+(a.y*b.x)
   +(a.x*b.z)+(a.z*b.x)+(a.y*b.y)
   +(a.y*b.z)+(a.z*b.y)
   +(a.z*b.z)
```

so I divide it to 3 bracket terms per each component of `c`. Its important to sort the terms by magnitude to prevent rounding errors as much as possible. Along the summing of terms I just accumulate the error similarly like in addition.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer! I was successful in increasing the zoom upto ```4x``` using our old method discussed previously. I used a ```vec2```, but after its limit is reached I get pixelation similar to "broken glass" ! But, anyways, I'm continuing my efforts to increase precision further. But, I feel that there is little room for optimization in these techniques. But anyways its absolutely amazing and mind blowing! :)

Comment: @VivekanandV this should work much better than `double` so not just 4x zoom increase to `float` but few 1000x or more then `double` I can go to 10^14 zooms I think this might got much higher. However is very slooow (on CPU) and still there must be some edge case where precission is going be lost as higher zooms get blank black instead of image ... but it might be also some bug in my implementation of Mandelbrot instead of high precision math using vec3 as when I compare double and vec3 results they the same ...

Comment: @VivekanandV I am thinking of testing this by doing all operation on double behind the scenes and then use `+` with vec3 math. If the result changes to blank I know error is there ...  if not do `-` like this ,... then `*` .... to isolate the problem however did not have any time/mood for this yet and does not look like there will be for next few days either  ...